# Syntax errors when creating unique constraints in SQL table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Prior to this, I was receiving errors saying that I needed unique constraints for the third table, but now I can't figure out the syntax for creating the constraints.

```
create table actors
    (AID        varchar(3),
     name       varchar(20),
     primary key (AID, name)     
     unique (AID)
        );
create table movies
    (MID        varchar(3), 
     title      varchar(15), 
     rtr        numeric(12,2),
     primary key (MID, title, rtr)
     unique (MID)
        );
create table actor_role
    (role_name  varchar(20),
     MID        varchar(3), 
     AID        varchar(3), 
     primary key (role_name),
     foreign key (MID) references movies(MID)
        on delete set null,
     foreign key (AID) references actors(AID)
            on delete set null
    );
```

I have tried a few other variations I found online but can't seem to figure it out. I'm using Postgres on DbVisualizer 11.0.4 if that has any effect.

Comment: Use int data type for id columns.

Comment: There is a missing comma after the primary key of movies.

Comment: Have the id column alone as primary key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Your code works](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=93c72dba0719f374d5a8ac241a5e6f48) - provided that you add the missing commas before `unique` constraint in the actors and movies table.

Let me pinpoint, though, that the constraints on the actors and movies table do not make sense. You are declaring the first column as `unique`, and then create a primary key constraint that includes it, plus two other columns. This is redundant, and obfuscating.

I would recommend the first column as a primary key. The other constraint is not needed, unless, maybe, you want the actor's name to be unique in the table? If so:

```
create table actors (
    AID        varchar(3),
    name       varchar(20),
    primary key (AID),     
    unique (name)
);
```

As for table movies, you might mean:

```
create table movies(
    MID        varchar(3), 
    title      varchar(15), 
    rtr        numeric(12,2),
    primary key (MID)
    unique (title, rtr)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a comma before the `unique`.  That said, a composite primary key index seems unlikely.  I am guessing you really want:

```
create table actors (
     AID        varchar(3) primary key,
     name       varchar(20) unique
);
```

The same is true of the other tables.  And 20 characters for a name seems on the short side.